# Search not working on Gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have Implemented the Search on gridview for columns from [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-GridView-records-data-on-TextBox-KeyPress-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx)
 link. I implemented as per my requirement.But it is not working for me. Please see the code for your reference:-

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdCSRPageData" runat="server" Width="100%" border="1" Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;" CellPadding="3" class="hoverTable" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#E5E5E5" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" ShowFooter="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="grdCSRPageData_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="grdCSRPageData_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="grdCSRPageData_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="grdCSRPageData_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="grdCSRPageData_RowDeleting" OnRowCommand="grdCSRPageData_RowCommand" OnDataBound="grdCSRPageData_DataBound">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="page_title" HeaderText="Page Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="page_description" HeaderText="Page Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_title" HeaderText="Meta Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_keywords" HeaderText="Meta Keywords" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_description" HeaderText="Meta Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="15" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit/Delete" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete?')">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </span>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnInsertRecord" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Insert" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle Width="15%"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Also see the JS script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quicksearch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.form-control').each(function (i) {
            $(this).quicksearch("[id*=grdCSRPageData] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                    return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also see the code behind for your ref:-

```
  protected void grdCSRPageData_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        for (int i = 0; i < grdCSRPageData.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
            TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
            txtSearch.Attributes["placeholder"] = grdCSRPageData.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            txtSearch.CssClass = "form-control";
            cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
            row.Controls.Add(cell);
        }
        grdCSRPageData.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
    }
```

Changes for the grid

```
 protected void grdUser_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        for (int i = 0; i < grdUser.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
            TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
            txtSearch.Attributes["placeholder"] = grdUser.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            txtSearch.CssClass = "form-control HaydaBre";

            if (grdUser.Columns[i].HeaderText != "Action" && grdUser.Columns[i].HeaderText != "" && grdUser.Columns[1].HeaderText != "Select") // && grdUser.Columns[i].HeaderText != "" && grdUser.Columns[i].HeaderText != null && grdUser.Columns[i].HeaderText != "Select")
            {
                cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
            }
            row.Controls.Add(cell);
        }
        grdUser.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
    }
```

When I add the `HeaderText` != `Select`. It stops working for the first column, but it works for the other column

Comment: any way of working ?

Comment: Since this is a client side implementation, have debugged your code for example using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). then please share the error message here.. Your code works on my side...

Comment: @wooer: Error message, U mean to say is the Console error ?

Comment: Yes, the console message.

Comment: @wooer: I got two error. 1)TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function
$('.sortable').sortable();

2)TypeError: $(...).quicksearch is not a function
$(this).quicksearch("[id*=grdCSRPageData] tr:not(:has(th))", {

Comment: Then, Can you validate Jquery is loaded (barely the above link loads),  Sortable's and quicksearch's Js files' path is correct (your page can reach those files in correct order <they are loaded after Jquery>).

Comment: @wooer: How to validate ? As Sortable js is in the masterpage and quicksearch js file is in the aspx page where I need searh implementation. Also see the jsfiddle for your ref:- http://jsfiddle.net/d8yftm4e/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65563/discussion-between-wooer-and-nadeem-khan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of elements with form-control class. So can you change your C# code to be:

```
protected void grdCSRPageData_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        for (int i = 0; i < grdCSRPageData.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
            TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
            txtSearch.Attributes["placeholder"] = grdCSRPageData.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            txtSearch.CssClass = "form-control HaydaBre";
            cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
            row.Controls.Add(cell);
        }
        grdCSRPageData.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
    }
```

and your JS code to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.HaydaBre').each(function (i) {
            $(this).quicksearch("[id*=grdCSRPageData] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                    return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks wooer, really appreciated your help. It is now working as charm for me..!! :)

Comment: That's why we all are here.. That's great to hear that I helped though. And that must also be great to have a manager who has appreciation for his employees :) Thank you. Have a nice day and beware of the css class names :)

Comment: Does Firebug say anything?

Comment: I didn't checked. I made one change in codebehind and it stopped working

Comment: And the change was.. ?

Comment: 1. what does Firebug say? please check. 2 you wrote `grdUser.Columns[1].HeaderText != "Select"` -> **1** instead of **`i`** Do you want to test if the second column header text is not `"Select"` ? (Which seems strange in a loop :) ) If not than change it to `i` and test again.

Comment: When I repalce 1 with `i`. It stops working. I dont want to test the second column. I just want that, where there is no column which is coming from table should not generate the textbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67370/discussion-between-wooer-and-nadeem-khan).

Comment: hi, I got the solution for that. Just added the some code in javascript. And it worked. :)

Comment: hi wooer, do let me know once you come. By the time i m implementing that

Comment: Sir, the problem is nearby to get resolve now. Just the dropdown has to be set properly.. :)